# Add UUID for request till response in cloudwatch logs

Tags: logging, slf4j, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am pushing logs from gradle project to Cloudwatch. The configuration looks like

```
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-datetime-format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%L",
          "awslogs-region": "ap-southeast-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/xxxx"
        }
      }
```

I want to push some UUID to each log so that I can distinguish each request till its response.

Basically, I am looking for something like %X regex in log4j2.yml file where we just set a UUID in MDC context and it is printed for every log.

How can I configure cloudwatch config to use unique identifier for logs for request till response?

I saw [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#awslogs-multiline-pattern) but I am not finding any proper regex to add-in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a unique log stream for each request, and the simple answer is that you can't.

You're using the `awslogs` driver, which is configured at the time the container starts, and does not change while the container is running. You could *possibly* do this with an agent configuration if you use default (stdout/stderr) logging and are running on an EC2 instance, but that would be a really bad idea.

I'm assuming that your container processes web requests. In which case, if you did hack something together to send each request to a different stream, here's what would happen:

- You would almost certainly run into the `CreateLogStream` throttling rate of 50 requests per second.
- You would end up with thousands (or, depending on your site's activity, millions) of individual log streams. This will be a nightmare to manage, since AWS does not automatically delete streams. Just listing them all would cause you to hit the quota in `DescribeLogStreams`.

Instead, I recommend that you add your UUID to your request *inside your app*, via the MDC, and use [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) to extract the messages for a single request.